# See Debug Lines of webservice in console app

Tags: c#, rest, debugging

first of all sorry if this question exists elsewhere, I wasn't able to find a similar subject.

I had a simple console doing some stuff, and at some point logging in console the progress. I added a Web API 2 service containing the business part of my app, and I use a HttpClient to call it.

My question is : how can I redirect the console logs from the WS to the calling console app, in order not to loose track of the progress made ?
My current "logs" are basic Console.WriteLine("Some Random Message") and the WS runs synchronously, but I'm open to any solution.

I saw some solutions with ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput, but it seems to work only with .exe if I'm right, so I don't think I can use it there.

I can provide snippets if needed, I didn't judge it relevant as it is more a concept question than anything.

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english !

Edit with some snippet :

Calling console App :

```
 public static void Run()
 {
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Data = "data"});
    var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = Client.PostAsync("url", httpContent).Result;
    return response;
 }
```

Webservice :

```
 [HttpPost, Route("Run")]
 public IHttpActionResult Run()
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Log To Output");
 }
```

Comment: What is a WS? And yes, a sample code would be advantagues, as otherwise it´s hard to guess what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: "but it seems to work only with .exe if I'm right" Sure, only a **process** (that is something that is executable - an *.exe usually) can log anything. So you have to redirect the log of the process running your code.

Comment: There is a host of your WS and client - an app which uses HttpClient. Usually all debug logs are stored in host computer and client only gets summarized messages which are relevant to client. So you don't need to redirect anything. Just use any logging framework (like log4net) to store logs to file or smth. Or you can use [enable web api tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api) to do similar thing.

Comment: @HimBromBeere WS stands for WebService. I'll edit with a sample soon Thanks for the explanation about the process, didn't figure it out

Comment: @Reniuz Storing it to a file would be very complicated, I'll try to look into Tracing, thanks !

Comment: What so complicated?

Comment: Storing it on the server and accessing it would be okay, but I don't think my boss will accept this solution as he doesn't like the storage of temporary files ont the server disk .. I'll tell him about it though

Comment: You only enable tracing and storing logs when you need not constantly. I don't know the use case of an app, but if you need some sort of monitoring then there should be another approach to deal with it.